# hide jkmegamenu only on document click

Tags: jquery, megamenu

I am using [jkmegamenu](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.shtml) to show sub menus on click of an anchor tag. I need to hide the sub menus on clicking inside the document or the anchor tag again. I was able to hide the submenus only on clicking the anchor tag with the below modification(removing the mouseleave:

```
megamenu.$menuobj.bind("click **mouseleave**", function(e){
        var menuinfo=jkmegamenu.megamenus[parseInt(this.getAttribute("_megamenupos"))]
        menuinfo.hidetimer=setTimeout(function(){ //add delay before hiding menu
            jkmegamenu.hidemenu(e, parseInt(menuinfo.$menuobj.get(0).getAttribute("_megamenupos")))
        }, jkmegamenu.delaytimer)
    })
```

But how can i hide the menu on clicking anywhere inside the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on the `window` for a click event and check what element on the page was clicked. If it is `not` a part of your sub menu, you can hide your sub menu. Using jQuery you can accomplish like:

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('submenu-link')) {
        // hide menu here
    });
});
```

That is of course if you navigation looks something like this:

```
<a class="submenu-link" href="/" ... />
```